# Как во вложеном цикле изменить стиль кнопки VUE

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Есть код, нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся стиль только этой кнопки, сделать надо во вложенном массиве через цикл v-for

```
 <ul class="list" v-for="(compareItem, index) in compareItems">
   <li class="list-item" 
   v-for="(item, idx) in compareItem" 
   :key="`${index}${idx}`"
   >
          <button class="btn-compare"
               @click="clicked(index,idx)"
               v-if="isClicked" 
              :class="{active: isClicked[index]}"
           >
               {{compareItem[idx]}}
           </button>

       </li>
</ul>
```

```
 clicked(index, idx) {
            this.$set(this.isClicked, index, !this.isClicked[index])
```

Как передать в this.$set подмассив? Тоесть
 `this.$set(this.isClicked, (index, idx), !this.isClicked[index][idx])`

Но тогда будет ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно реализовать такую задачу?

Comment: Попробуй просто `this.isClicked[index][idx] = !this.isClicked[index][idx]; this.isClicked.splice(0, 0);` - вызов метода `splice` запустит ререндеринг (если `isClicked` был должным образом объявлен в локальном состоянии компонента). Это конечно страшный хак... но сделать красиво и надежно, в любом случае не получится при таком дурном состоянии на массиве массивов.

Comment: А как в html передавать значение? :class="{ 'active' : isClicked[index][idx]}" выдает ошибку

Comment: Бинд класса правильный (и должно работать при правильной инициализации лок. стейта). Какую именно ошибку ты получаешь?

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

(found in <Root>)

Comment: Значит, инициализировал массив массивов коряво - то есть, на момент рендеринга разметки либо `isClicked === undefined`, либо `isClicked[index] === undefined`. Прямо в функции `data` должно быть присвоено начальное значение свойству `isClicked` (массив массивов, с соблюдением всех размерностей), иначе первый же рендеринг шаблона сломается.

Comment: А если изначально размер неизвестен как тогда быть?
Когда задал размер всё заработало, спасибо)

Comment: Менять логику кода компонента. Например, самым простым решением будет хранение "флага кликнутости" в свойстве непосредственно самого объекта (`item`) - если допустимо дополнение объектов из пропсов новыми свойствами... а если недопустимо, то можно например вместо массива массивов завести в локальном состоянии хэштаблицу для этого флага (используя в качестве индексов все то же значение `${index}${idx}`, которое у тебя биндится ключевым. И не забывать чистить/переносить содержимое этой хэштаблицы, когда модель меняется).

Comment: Еще, можно кнопку вынести в самостоятельный компонент с "флагом кликнутости" в его собственном локальном состоянии (и с инкапсуляцией логики его изменения).